# In Angular, is it possible to load different modules depending upon whether the user is authenticated or not?

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-guards, angular-route-guards

For example, the URL: www.example.com should load one module if the user is authenticated, else it should load a different module.

**I have tried using guards, but it didn't work as I expect it to.**

**I am pretty new to Angular. It would be much appreciated if someone could write a sample routes array for demonstration. :)**

If the user is not authenticated, I want my routes to work something like below:

```
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    loadChildren: './register/register.module#RegisterModule'
  }
```

Else, if the user is authenticated, I want my routes to work something like below:

```
  {
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
  },
  {
    path: 'profile',
    loadChildren: './user-profile/user-profile.module#UserProfileModule'
  }
```

Comment: read this article, you need `route guard`
https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-route-guards-bf7a4ca13ae3

Comment: I tried. It didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this using the `CanActivate` guard (checking route access).

`CanActivate`
Checks to see if a user can visit a route.

Having said that I would expect you to redirect to a different route after `guardCheck`.

You should not have the router configuration to accommodate two different components or modules on same route. 
You can add them as child of a route and decide routing if you need them on same route.

**Update**:

I came across the concept of `matcher` which can be used to load two different routes at same path:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'list',
  matcher: matcherForAuthenticatedRoute,
  loadChildren: './user/register#RegisterModule'
},
{
  path: 'list',
  matcher: matcherForTheOtherRoute,
  loadChildren: './user/home#HomeModule'
}]
```

Now our matching logic depends on two functions, that can be as below:

```
export function matcherForAuthenticatedRoute(
 segments: UrlSegment[],
 group: UrlSegmentGroup,
 route: Route) {
  const userService =  appInjector.get(MyService);
  const isPathMatch = segments[0].path === route.path;
  const isUserAuthenticated = userService.isUserAuthenticated('userId');      
  if(isPathMatch && isUserTypeMatch) { 
    return {consumed: [segments[0]]};
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

We can define `appInjector` after bootstraping the app and export it to be used:

```
appInjector = componentRef.injector;
```

Comment: I also want this if the user is authenticated:
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule'
    }

Comment: How should I load two completely different modules on the same URL, with the condition user is authenticated or not?

Comment: I would expect you to redirect to a diffrent route after guardCheck. You can't have the router configuration to accommodate two different components or modules on same route. You can add them as child of a route and decide routing if you need them on same route.

Comment: @FaisalAlam, check this may be helpful for what you need: https://medium.com/@lenseg1/loading-different-angular-modules-or-components-on-routes-with-same-path-2bb9ba4b6566